# Suppress extra inter-character horizontal space in lstlistings

Tags: spacing, listings

When I use the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package, there is a bit of extra space between characters, even in a monospaced font.

For code, I use a monospaced font (`basicstyle=\ttfamily`), and I want to obtain the same horizontal spacing as in an ordinary verbatim environment.

For algorithms, I use a variable-width font, and I want to have the same horizontal spacing as in ordinary text.

MWE illustrating a code snippet in a monospaced font (I see the same output for the `lstlistings` blocks if I don't include the `alltt` package):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

What I want to typeset:
\begin{alltt}
\textbf{int} hello_world = 3;      \textit{/* alltt */}
\end{alltt}
\vspace{1em}

What I want to type:
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=C]
int hello_world = 3;      /* lstlisting (ttfamily, C) */
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{1em}

Default listing, for reference:
\begin{lstlisting}
int hello_world = 3;      /* lstlisting (default) */
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

How do I obtain the desired character spacing?

Comment: The `columns=fullflexible` option will do what you want.

Comment: @AlanMunn after upvoting your comment I realize that now spaces from the source are collapsed into just one; is there a work-around?

Comment: @jfbu Try `columns=flexible`.

Comment: @AlanMunn that does it indeed!